# Sharepoint online: Programmatically post to news feed

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, feed

I want to create a webpart which can post data to a specific Sharepoint's news feed, but have been unable to locate any good documentation. The only link I found was:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e9ad06a1-831d-8ed0-c76e-8b049f14216f%28Office.15%29.aspx

**My question is:** what method can I use to post data to a Sharepoint-site's news feed?

In the link they mention that you can post to "the URL of a site feed". Is that the same as a news feed? Anyone who has done something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use JSOM or REST API to achieve it.

**REST API**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   
    $.ajax( {
        url: weburl + "/_api/social.feed/my/Feed/Post",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 
            'restCreationData':{
                '__metadata':{ 
                    'type':'SP.Social.SocialRestPostCreationData'
                },
                'ID': null, 
                'creationData':{ 
                    '__metadata':{ 
                        'type':'SP.Social.SocialPostCreationData'
                    },
                    'ContentText': "the post content text",
                    'UpdateStatusText':false
                } 
            } 
        }),
        headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log("success to post ");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
            alert("POST error:\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**JSOM**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.userprofiles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(WritePost, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
function WritePost() {
    var oclientContext;
    var ofeedManager;
    var oresultThread;

    // Initialize the current client context and the SocialFeedManager instance.
    oclientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    ofeedManager = new SP.Social.SocialFeedManager(oclientContext);

    // Add a link to be included in the post.
    var olinkDataItem = new SP.Social.SocialDataItem();
    olinkDataItem.set_itemType(SP.Social.SocialDataItemType.link);
    olinkDataItem.set_text('My blog url');
    olinkDataItem.set_uri('http://sundarnarasiman.net');
    var osocialDataItems = [ olinkDataItem ];

    // Set up the post content
    var opostCreationData = new SP.Social.SocialPostCreationData();
    opostCreationData.set_contentText('The text for the post, which contains a {0}.');
    opostCreationData.set_contentItems(osocialDataItems);

    // Write the post
    oresultThread = ofeedManager.createPost(null, opostCreationData);
    oclientContext.executeQueryAsync(WriteSucceeded, WriteFailed);
}

function WriteSucceeded(sender, args) {
    //$get("ResultMessage").innerText = 'Successfully posted the message to Posts';
}
function WriteFailed(sender, args) {
    //$get("ResultMessage").innerText = 'Failure in writing message' + args.get_message();
}
</script>
```

Refer to:

[Post/Reply a post by Social feed REST API in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.csdn.net/Tristan_Dong/article/details/42269025)

[How to publish a post to SharePoint Social Feed using SharePoint 2013 JSOM](http://sundarnarasiman.net/2014/02/02/how-to-publish-a-post-to-sharepoint-social-feed-using-sharepoint-2013-jsom/)